# xhtml changes are not reflected using Jrebel and JSF Mojarra 2.1.7

Tags: jsf-2, jrebel

Java changes are reflecting immediately but not changes on the xhtml pages are showing up after page refresh.

rebel.xml

```
<classpath>
    <dir 
        name="${rebel.workspace.path}Projects/test/target/classes">
    </dir>                      
</classpath>
<web>
    <link target="\">
        <dir 
            name="${rebel.workspace.path}Projects/test/src/main/webapp" />
    </link>
</web>
```

Comment: Refreshing the page does not resolve the issue.

Comment: This is very easily googled. You need to configure it and have rebel.xml in place

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target attribute matches the context root of your webapp. And that the rebel.xml exists in the webapp which you have deployed.  There isn't enough supporting detail in the question to give any other suggestions at this point.